# why my project bar doesn't show when I start the Arena program

Tags: arena-simulation

I can't visualize my project bar which are supposed to give the primary types of objects I will work in.

I open as usually the Arena but this time it doesn't show the project bar, and I don't understand what's wrong. I should be able to use the data definition, data creation and others but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

This arena software's user interface is very unintuitive! If you go to "View", there is a checkbox to toggle the "Project Bar".

[image]